# git remote add with other SSH port

Tags: git, ssh, port

In Git, how can I add a remote origin server when my host uses a different SSH port?

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@host/srv/git/example
```

Answer (score 703, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@host:1234/srv/git/example
```

`1234` is the ssh port being used

Comment: Thx. Just a complement : in the path part, use absolute path, not a relative path to user home directory...

Comment: @Snicolas : Why shall one not use a relative path?

Comment: @Sincolas
It works if you have the repo in the users home directory: **/home/someuser/git-repos/example.git** --> **ssh://someuser@<host>:<port>/~/git-repos/example.git** .
btw: you get a _<name>.git_ repo by **git clone --bare <adress>**

Comment: @Jameo It *is* an absolute path.

Comment: Using gitolite and git 1.8.1.2, I had to use relative paths with this (i.e. `ssh://git@myhost.com:1234/project.git`, not `ssh://git@myhost.com:1234/~/repositories/project.git`). I'm guessing gitolite does some automagic here.

Comment: @RyanP see the other comments.

Comment: Note that it will not work if you remove the protocol. i.e if you try the following, it will not work.
`git remote add origin user@host:1234/srv/git/example`

Comment: In my case I had to add trailing `/` to make it work, e.g. `ssh://user@host:1234/srv/git/example/` otherwise git failed to reach remote repo

Comment: `git remote set-url origin ssh://user@example.com:10000/aaa/bbbb/ccc.git`

Comment: Using `ssh://git@myhost.com:1234/project.git` doesn't work. It always gives `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`.
However using `git@myhost.com:1234/project.git` solves the problem.

Comment: This is still valid answer, we're using this syntax on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with git v2.7.4. Thumbs up for the answer, and thumbs down for git not supporting `-p` or similar port override argument!

Comment: For a relative path use Konrad's (better) answer with brackets.

Comment: I have password-less ssh access to my git server named myhost, and I simply do the following: ```git remote add origin myhost:/srv/git/example```

Comment: This approach seems to not work in combination with GIT LFS.
Thanks for it anyways!

Answer (score 156):

You need to edit your ~/.ssh/config file. Add something like the following:

```
Host example.com
    Port 1234
```

A quick google search shows a [few](http://scie.nti.st/2007/11/14/hosting-git-repositories-the-easy-and-secure-way) [different](http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/accessing-git-over-ssh-on-a-non-standard-port-217.html) resources that explain it in more detail than me.

Comment: It did work for me. I like this approach better than sticking it in the git remote. Thanks! No need to specify an absolute path either this way.

Comment: This works great. Also that way I can have a specific key instead of the default id_rsa. Not only that, my server is picky and more or less you have to have it right quickly enough which fails if you include password. So I use the `PasswordAuthentication no` as well.

Comment: It's better to have it in the remote than hiding it in the config file like this: when you have everything in just one place you can never forget  about the different port number and you can simply copy and paste the URL for anyone else to use.

Comment: @MarcH It actually depends upon the situation. I like to use random port numbers on on my VPS instances. Having the port inside the config file is one way you can withhold that information from collaborators (That's when you have multiple remotes, the deployment remote host is different from the internal Source Code repo).

Comment: @RagunathJawahar I don't think using random port numbers is a very common use case.

Comment: @MarcH Agree, that's why I began with 'It actually depends'.

Comment: This should work if you get the config file (and other .ssh options and permissions) right.  The other advantage is that all other ssh services will get the right port as well (e.g., rsync).

Comment: And then in the .git/config file you can simply use `host:srv/git/example` as the value of the URL (or use `git remote add host:/srv/git/example`. See `man git-pull` to learn about the possible URL/host syntaxes.

Comment: Thanks, this works for GitLab Docker container when map to port not 22, spend whole day finnally get things work.

Comment: This is the best answer, I think

Answer (score 44):

Rather than using the `ssh://` protocol prefix, you can continue using the conventional URL form for accessing git over SSH, with one small change. As a reminder, [the conventional URL is](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server):

```
git@host:path/to/repo.git
```

To specify an alternative port, put brackets around the `user@host` part, including the port:

```
[git@host:port]:path/to/repo.git
```

But if the port change is merely temporary, you can tell git to use a different SSH command instead of changing your repository’s remote URL:

```sh
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -p port'
git clone git@host:path/to/repo.git # for instance
```

Comment: Adding the square brackets around the git@host:port worked beautifully for me. I am using gitlab and on that server it requires a non standard port but I also cannot use the absolute path to the repo (I don't know it). Thank you

Comment: This seems like the most flexible method to me as it supports relative paths and doesn't rely on ssh configs

Comment: Ehm, it's GIT_SSH_COMMAND, check this out https://git-scm.com/docs/git

Comment: While adding it as a remote using `git remote add`, I had to wrap the URL in double quotes to have this syntax work. Like so: `git remote add gitea "[git@host:port]:path/to/repo.git"`

Comment: @raisinrising That’s unrelated to Git, it depends on the shell you’re using. For sh/Bash/… the quotes are *not* necessary here.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Ah that makes sense, thank you. I am running `zsh` FWIW.

Comment: This worked to add a port number to a Git URL that looked like: ```git@server.com:repos/myrepo.git``` in my .git/config file.

Comment: You need to be a little careful about square brackets, as they are a globbing character.  For example, if the name `h:path/to/repo.git` exists then the glob `[git@host:port]:path/to/repo.git` will match it.  It's an unlikely name, so usually the glob won't match and the string will expand with no change.

Answer (score 41):

Best answer doesn't work for me. I needed `ssh://` from the beggining.

```
# does not work
git remote set-url origin user@example.com:10000/aaa/bbbb/ccc.git
# work
git remote set-url origin ssh://user@example.com:10000/aaa/bbbb/ccc.git
```

Comment: Debian 10 working in another ssh port. Testing ssh -T git@github.com got Error connection time out. Then this setup git remote set-url origin git@github.com:22/USER/REPOSITORY.git fix the problem. Thanks Kujiy!

Answer (score 19):

For those of you editing the `./.git/config`

```
[remote "external"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  url = ssh://evanc@www.foo.com:11720/aaa/bbb/ccc                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/external/*
```

Comment: Perfect. One question though, how do I do this for submodules? It does not seem to work.

Answer (score 7):

for gitlab, example ssh port is 2224, therefore:

> git remote add ssh://git@192.168.1.100:2224/your_group/your_project.git

Answer (score 6):

Had a similar issue trying to connect to my git server

( have a [gitea](https://docs.gitea.io/en-us/install-with-docker/) server in a docker container with ssh-port configured to `2022`, instead of standard 22, here as an example `my-git-server.lan` ).

1. create ssh key-pair (quiet, without password)

```
$ ssh-keygen -q -N '' -b 4096 -f ~/.ssh/mykeyfile
```

(this will create two files: public-key `mykeyfile.pub` and private-key `mykeyfile` without any extension)

2. display contents of the public-key and copy/paste it to your profile's SSH keys in your git-server (similar to how you would do it on [Github](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) )

```
$ cat ~/.ssh/mykeyfile.pub
```

3. add following lines to ssh-config to specify git-server's hostname, port and key-file

```
$ nano ~/.ssh/config
Host my-git-server.lan
  HostName my-git-server.lan
  User git
  Port 2022
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/mykeyfile
```

(notice that the username is **always** `git`, regardless of your actual username on your git-server)

4. test ssh connection to your git-server using public-key, .. and receive a success message

```
$ ssh -T git@my-git-server.lan
Hi there, username! You've successfully authenticated with the key named /Users/username/.ssh/mykeyfile.pub
```

.. use **-v** "verbose mode" to analyse any errors:

```
$ ssh -Tvvv git@my-git-server.lan
```

(again, notice that the username is **always** `git`)

5. specify your remote address `ssh://git@my-git-server.lan:2022/alex/myproject.git` for your local git repository (again, notice the user **git** and the port **2022**), .. check remote configuration

```
$ cd your/local/git/repository/folder
$ git remote add my-git-server ssh://git@my-git-server.lan:2022/alex/myproject.git
$ git remote -v
```

( here you also see that on my git-server my actual user is *alex* and repository is *myproject* )

Done! You can now work with your git-server .. fetch/commit/push etc.

( this is a copy of my post on [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/a/1088209/511021) )

---

**Update**: as rightly noted in the comments - you do not necessarily need to specify port **2022** in the remote-url, since it is already configured in `~/.ssh/config` file as `PORT 2022`.

Comment: Thank you this works great. One little thing, I did not need to add the PORT to the remote URL. Just create the host in `~/.ssh/config` and it automatically will use the port specified there

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at how to set up your **~/.ssh/config** file correctly.

You can specify different settings for different hosts easily.

To solve your problem you would set

```
Host github.com 
Port 22 
Host * 
Port 1234
```

Have a look at the **ssh_config** manual page, it explains everything you need to know on the first few pages.

Answer (score -1):

1.git remote **add** ${shortname} ${url}

2.git remote **remove** shortname (is remove a remote)

3.git remote **-v**  (is to see your current remote list)

4.git **push** remote branch

5.git remote **rename** A B (rename A to B)

6.git remote **show** shortname (show remote info)

**All this works for me.**