# Gitosis cloning out on non-default port

Tags: windows, git, ssh, gitosis

When gitos-admin with

`git clone ssh://gitosis@192.168.1.1:gitosis-admin.git`

I couldn't connect because ssh is connecting to port 22 and my ssh is running on 2211. So, I searched the internet for a solution. It should be as easy as adding the port to my .ssh/config file. I added the following to the file (which I hat to create)

```
Host bml
HostName 192.168.1.1
Port 2211
```

When executing:

`git clone ssh://gitosis@bml:gitosis-admin.git`

I get the following error:

`Cloning into 'gitosis-admin'...
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

Which suggest that my config file is invalid or my config file is not used.

So... I tested it with a host that didn't exist

`git clone ssh://gitosis@bmlsomething:gitosis-admin.git`

Which resultated in the same error as before

`Cloning into 'gitosis-admin'...
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Bad file number
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

This suggests that the config file is not used (okey could still be an invalid file, but would expect atleast a different error).

How can I fix this? BTW, I'm on Windows 7 :-s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://jamesreubenknowles.com/git-over-a-non-standard-ssh-port-1505), `git clone ssh://user@host:port/repository` should work.

As far as I'm aware, the `~/.ssh/config` is not used by Windows.

EDIT: This question is also discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767850/git-on-custom-ssh-port/5767880#5767880).