# Specify port for git clone

Tags: git, port

I would like to know if it is possible to specify a port number while using  git clone. I do not use ssh, I would like to clone a repository from the github website.

Thank you!

Comment: I guess you can relate here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767850/git-on-custom-ssh-port

Comment: Github serves HTTPS over standard port 443.

Comment: To be honest, I saw this post, but I did not understand it. For ssh://git@mydomain.com:[port]/gitolite-admin, I need to replace the "port" with the wanted port, but the "mydomain" needs to be replaced by github? If yes, how do I specify the repository I want to clone?

Comment: If you need to clone it from the github website, why do you need to specify the port at all? You should clone from a url like `https://github.com/username/project.git`, there should be no need for a port at all. Can you clarify why you think you need to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git On Custom SSH Port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767850/git-on-custom-ssh-port)