# SSH not working getting ssh error fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab

if I try anything on my own gitlab server over ssh it gives the following error,
fatal: protocol error: bad line length character: git@. I tested this command inside git BASH, Powershell and vscode. Inside all 3 I get the same error. I tested all my keys and they are working when I use ssh receive package method when I ran this method info about the master shows up and a welcome $USERNAME you are logged in message appears. So why isn't this working?

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: i am running git clone git@ServerHostname:Username/Mygit.git

Comment: What software are you running on `ServerHostname` to host your repositories? Is Git installed on the server?

Comment: I am running gitlab on the server and when using HTTP everything is fine and when testing ssh connection everything works as well, but when using git@servename/repo.git  git@ gives an error it is something locally with git@ is looks like it isn't recognized. My ssh server is on a different port btw.

Comment: (a) `git@ServerHostname:Username/Mygit.git` and `git@servename/repo.git` are different things. Make sure to separate the server hostname and the path with a `:`, and make sure to include the GitLab user part of the path (I think that's required). (b) Have you tried [specifying the custom port](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5767850/354577)?

Comment: the first step you explained was the way I did it as well. The second step worked as well but froze because putty tried to use the ssh key inside the cache, but I am changing to the OpenSSH agent from windows. This one wasn't working for me at first but I came across a solution and apparently the OpenSSH agent is disabled by default in service management. So I will try that first and let you know about my result.

Comment: I have git working now but when trying to use it inside vscode it says permission denied (public key) but when using the command line or PowerShell everything works can this be fixed

Comment: That sounds like a different issue, Andrea. Please search the site to see if anybody else has asked about "vscode permission denied (public key)" or similar. If you don't find anything feel free to ask a new question.

Comment: Okay thank you I searched for it but no one seems to have a solution I don t get this because this is the end goal I think but thanks for your help needs this to be closed or something?

Comment: You can delete it if you want. Otherwise other users will probably vote to close and eventually delete it, so the end result will be the same.