# "ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer" error when trying to connect to remote repository on git

Tags: git, github

I'm very new to github, I started using it about two weeks ago. Everything worked perfectly, I was able to push and pull from my remote repository. Today, however, when I tried to pull from it I got this error message:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

When I try to do anything that connects to my remote github repository (push, pull, fetch, etc), in fact, it gives me back the same error.

When I type in this command: "ssh -T git@github.com", I just get:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I didn't modify any settings in my repository or in my SSH keys or anything so I have no idea why it stopped working all of a sudden. What could be the problem?

Comment: Execute `ssh -vvv -T git@github.com`, it will show debug information about the connection.

Comment: @GonzaloMatheu, I executed it and it returned this (I'll split it into two comments because of the character limit):  OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
debug1: Reading configuration data /c/Users/b/.ssh/config
debug1: /c/Users/b/.ssh/config line 2: Applying options for github.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to github.com [192.30.253.113] port 22.
debug1: Connection established. debug1: identity file /c/Users/b/.ssh/id_rsa type 0

Comment: debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /c/Users/b/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Comment: This question might help -> https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321968/trying-to-ssh-into-server-and-getting-key-load-public-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: I didn't understand much from it, could you please explain the solution provided there? It seems it's for a different context than github.

Comment: I have already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64100419/3437897

Answer (score 24):

I had a similar issue recently, I'm not sure whether its exactly the same as I got the connected user by following command.

> ssh -T git@gitlab.com

But when I try to push the code to remote repository I got same error.

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

After trying few solutions from the internet without success, I just tried `git init` and **it worked for me**. I hope this works only if the connection user has bound correctly.

Try it out Good Luck.. :)

Answer (score 18):

I also had this problem and I was able to fix it by restarting my internet connection.

I was so confused when git bash suddenly gave me that message. I did not do any alteration on my git repositories at all. Restarting my connection fixed it.

Comment: Same here. Switched to mobile bec my fiber was down and got this error suddenly for no apparent reason. So, the problem wasn't git.

Answer (score 10):

Do `git-init`. It will reinitialize the connection

Answer (score 4):

The same thing happened to me with Bitbucket today. I first tried `git init` as another reply suggested. No luck. Then simply enough, I just rebooted my PC and it all started working again.

Comment: I have been trying to push to git from terminal. Simply, closing and than reopening the terminal has solved the case.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same thing and this worked for me:

```
git config http.sslVerify "false"
```

And then:

```
git remote rename origin old-origin
```

and then instead of using ssh (git@YOUR_GIT_REPO.git) used the **https** url and set that as origin:

```
git remote add origin https://YOUR_GIT_REPO.git
```

Comment: This really worked!!

Comment: sadly, for GitHub: `remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.`

Comment: This helped behind a corporate proxy, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I got this error today and wondered what had gone wrong. Rebooted. Still bad.  Then I went to gitlab website and got a 503 Error indicating server unavailable.  gitlab was doing major maintenance on their site and said would be down for two hours.

I'm just posting this in case others have this problem.  In this case it was not a local problem but the remote git server. The git bash error message is quite cryptic. It said:

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
Connection reset by 2606:4700:90:0:f22e:fbec:5bed:a9b9 port 22
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case was because the ssh port at /etc/ssh/ssh_config file was changed.
Once I changed the port in /etc/ssh/ssh_config back to 22, I was able to connect to Gitlab.

Comment: Well, I was surprised this was never mentioned! in the answers!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767850/git-on-custom-ssh-port

Answer (score 1):

The access point you are using might be blocking certain type of communication.
I just faced the problem while using my university's wifi network and when I changed the connection to my mobile's service it worked just fine

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31400372)

Comment: No I do not have a question.
I was suggesting that the person with problem should make sure that the internet network s\he is using is not blocking certain traffic protocols

Comment: In my case this did answer the question. The connection to the server over port 22 (I suspect) was being blocked by my company's VPN, so disabling the vpn did resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

My case is same with @osama-heba in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71657806/11671779).

The solution is to change port. If it is 22, try to change to 443 and vice-versa.

1. In ubuntu, change the port on:

   ```bash
   sudo nano ~/.ssh/config
   ```
2. Try remove origin and add it again (here, I use GitHub for example),

   ```bash
   git remote rm origin
   git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPONAME.git
   ```
3. To test and initilaize connection, you can push or pull from the remote. Alternatively in GitHub, use:

   ```bash
   ssh -T git@github.com
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced this problem and I was unable to push anything to Github or even ssh into my Linux servers. After days of troubleshooting and researching, I realised it was to do with the internet connection I was connected to. When I connected to a different network (From a different provider), I was able to proceed normally with pushing to GitHub and SSH-ing to the Linux servers. Try to change your internet connection i.e to a different router/provider e.t.c and see if it also works for you.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize I had my wifi enabled and was having wifi issues. Disabled to use my landline and it instantly worked!

Answer (score 1):

So, I lost quite a bit of time on this, and the error was not difficult to fix so I figured I would just share it.

My goal was to clone a repo from gitlab to a remote server, and it was the first time that this remote server was acting as a client in a ssh communication.
Which means I never realized that I messed up when setting up the server, and that I did set the default SSH port to a custom port for BOTH the ssh client and ssh server.

So the actual fix was to edit the file  `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and commenting the line `Port XXXXX`.
If you want to keep this parameter, you can contact the ssh server on the right port (for gitlab.com it is the port 22, the default one):

> ssh -Tvvv git@gitlab.com -p 22

For cloning:

> git clone ssh://git@gitlab.com:22/some-path/some-name.git

I hope this will help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this error after a lot of struggle but I think its a dumb idea but it will work.

- Go to your git projects and clone it by HTTP link in your system.
- After you will get the git folder in your cloned project.
- copy that git folder and replace it with your SSL error showing project.
- then as usual git add. and so on .it will push normally.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error. But after deleting `.git` file it works fine
but somehow repeated again and again..

```
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer Connection reset by 13.234.210.38 port 22 fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights. and the repository exists.
```

Comment: same problem is here

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the problem because I got connected to one of the VPN

Comment: In my case for bitbucket, i have to turn on my VPN on my Mac OS, so this can be also bug from my VPN application.

Comment: In my case this answered the question. The connection to the server over port 22 (I suspect) was being blocked by my company's VPN, so disabling the vpn resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because I had incorrectly added a new remote repo (called `origin`) to my local git repo copy. You can view all your remotes like so:

```
$ git remote -v
origin  git@my-host.com:1234/my-path/my-project.git (fetch)
origin  git@my-host.com:1234/my-path/my-project.git (push)
```

Notice how the protocol (`ssh://`) is missing. This was causing the error for me. So just delete the old remote repos:

```
$ git remote rm origin
$ git remote -v
# empty
```

Then add the correct remote repo (called `origin`):

```
$ git remote add origin ssh://git@my-host.com:1234/my-path/my-project.git
$ git remote -v
origin  ssh://git@my-host.com:1234/my-path/my-project.git (fetch)
origin  ssh://git@my-host.com:1234/my-path/my-project.git (push)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to flush dns to resove this problem.

On Windows or WSL, open a admin powershell and execute `ipconfig /flushdns`. Then reboot WSL with `wsl.exe -t Ubuntu` and maybe the whole PC.

Answer (score 0):

None of these worked for me: restart wifi card, git init. I did not try rebooting.

I only see this problem when using IDE like PyCharm, and only since a couple of months.

In my case I have about 20 git repos hosted in github. If I only update a small number of git repos, the problem does not occur.

A web search indicates github does *not* throttle git fetch, but maybe it's a recent change that hasn't been announced yet?

Answer (score 0):

If you use clash, try adding port 22 mode in config file

- 'DST - PORT,22, Microsoft Services';

Reference: https://github.com/vernesong/Open Clash/issues/1960#issuecomment - 1052075603

https://docs.github.com/zh/authentication/troubleshooting-ssh/using-ssh-over-the-https-port

Answer (score -1):

This same problem also happened to me on my bitbucket repository, all I did was delete this repository and create another one with another name, and in locla I only modified the url of remote

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

To find out more about changing the URL of your repository, click on the link here : [changing-a-remotes-url](https://docs.github.com/en/github/using-git/changing-a-remotes-url)

Answer (score -1):

On Ubuntu + VSCode Terminal and using Bitbucket:

Restarting didn't work.

Reinitialize the repo worked:

```
$ git init
```