# ssh git kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: git, networking, ssh

few days ago everything working fine. now `ssh -T git@gitlab.com` and `ssh -T git@github.com` give me the same output `kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer`.

I've tried some suggestions on the internet with no luck.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and git version 2.25.1

`ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` give this output

```
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to gitlab.com [172.65.251.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_rsa type 0
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/fazar/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3
kex_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your ssh config, as in [`gitlab-org/gitlab` issue 121570](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/121570#note_452025935)

> I found out that the port in my /etc/ssh/ssh_config file was accidentally changed.
> Once I changed the port in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` back to 22, I was able to connect to Gitlab.

Try `ssh -Tv git@gitlab.com` to see more.

The [OP Fazar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4089781/fazar) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69006975/ssh-git-kex-exchange-identification-read-connection-reset-by-peer/69009495?noredirect=1#comment121991750_69009495) that upgrading from git 2.25 to 2.33 was enough to solve the issue.

---

Note: as seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837540/6309) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72837291/6309), you can also get that cryptic error message when the remote server as a planned (or unplanned?) maintenance.

So don't forget to check [GitHub Status](https://www.githubstatus.com/), [Status GitLab](https://status.gitlab.com/), [BitBucket status](https://bitbucket.status.atlassian.com/), or any other remote service you are using for hosting your repositories.

Comment: never change ssh_config, tried set the port manually still the same. I edit the question to include the verbose output

Comment: @Fazar Do you have a ~/.ssh/config file? Is there anything regardig ssh in your environment variables (`env|grep -i ssh`)? Would the issue persists with Git 2.33 (after a [ppa upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309))? Is your `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` registered to your GitLab user profile SSH setting?

Comment: @Fazar What changed, for you to accept the answer?

Comment: oh wow I update my git to 2.33.0 and it worked, thanks for the suggestions. maybe there's some git config I accidentally change and the update just fix that