# Try to pull and push to local server but git is not reading the repository correctly

Tags: git, gitlab

```
$ git pull <IP address here>:500/git@gitlab:softwaredev/apps.git
chase@<IP address here>'s password:
fatal: '500/git@gitlab:softwaredev/apps.git' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

My gitlab server is hosting at port 500 using docker, I'm trying to pull the repo to my local laptop, it seems like if I pecify which port it should go, the git will not read the repo location properly which results an repo not found.
I have tried to use http:// as well but similar thing happened as well.
Is there a way to let git know which part is repo which part is the ip address and the port number?

Comment: That's not the right syntax. Check out the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5767880/2307873