# Setting remote to use specified port for ssh

Tags: git

I have ssh keys setup to work on a specified port (e.g. 12345) and issued the following git command to set the origin on a local repo.

```
git remote add origin myusername@mydomain.com:12345/path/to/public_html/files/
```

I am getting the following error message when i try to push to origin.

```
ssh: connect to host mydomain.com port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

How do i set origin so it is using the proper port for ssh?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git remote add with other ssh port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596260/git-remote-add-with-other-ssh-port)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To specify a custom port, you have to add the ssh:// prefix. Otherwise, git interprets your 12345 as part of the project's path. See [URLs in the git-pull docs](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-pull.html#URLS). So:

```
git remote add origin ssh://myusername@mydomain.com:12345/path/to/public_html/files/
```