# gitolite with non-default port

Tags: ssh, gitolite

To clone a repository managed by gitolite one usually uses following syntax

```
git clone gitolite@server:repository
```

This tells the SSH client to connect to port 22 of *server* using *gitolite* as user name. When I try it with the port number:

```
git clone gitolite@server:22:repository
```

Git complains that the repository *22:repository* is not available. What syntax should be used if the SSH server uses a different port?

Comment: possible duplicate of [git remote add with other ssh port](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596260/git-remote-add-with-other-ssh-port)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The “SCP style” Git URL syntax (`user@server:path`) does not support including a port. To include a port, you must use an `ssh://` “Git URL”. For example:

```
ssh://gitolite@server:2222/repository
```

Note: As compared to `gitolite@server:repository`, this presents a slightly different repository path to the remote end (the absolute `/repository` instead of the relative path `repository`); Gitolite accepts both types of paths, other systems may vary.

---

An alternative is to use a `Host` entry in your `~/.ssh/config` (see your [*ssh_config(5)* manpage](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config)). With such an entry, you can create an “SSH host nickname” that incorporates the server name/address, the remote user name, and the non-default port number (as well as any other SSH options you might like):

```
Host gitolite
    User     gitolite
    HostName server
    Port     2222
```

Then you can use very simple Git URLs like `gitolite:repository`.

---

If you have to document (and or configure) this for multiple people, I would go with `ssh://` URLs, since there is no extra configuration involved.

If this is just for you (especially if you might end up accessing multiple repositories from the same server), it might be nice to have the SSH host nickname to save some typing.

Answer (score 2):

It is explained in great detail here: https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/ssh-troubleshooting.mkd#_appendix_4_host_aliases

Using a "host" para in ~/.ssh/config lets you nicely encapsulate all this within ssh and give it a short, easy-to-remember, name. Example:

```
host gitolite
    user git
    hostname a.long.server.name.or.annoying.IP.address
    port 22
    identityfile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Now you can simply use the one word gitolite (which is the host alias we defined here) and ssh will infer all those details defined under it -- just say ssh gitolite and git clone gitolite:reponame and things will work.