# Git - account not found

Tags: git

I am trying to push into my remote repo. But I always get this:

```
Account not found.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I get the same response when doing "git remote show origin".
When I do git remote -v I get this:

```
origin  sls@slsapp.com:1234/fitzler/fitzler-web-app.git (fetch)
origin  sls@slsapp.com:1234/fitzler/fitzler-web-app.git (push)
```

I have also tried ssh with success:

```
$ ssh sls@slsapp.com
Enter passphrase for key '/c/Users/jacobrohde/\.ssh\id_rsa':
Hi there! You are good to go. Just start pushing and pulling :)
Connection to slsapp.com closed.
```

What can be wrong here?

Comment: Have you contacted Springloops support?  The email address on their website is <support2.0@springloops.com>.

Comment: Actually I haven't. I was/am under the impression that something was wrong on my end. But I will try contact them and see what they say. Thanks!

Comment: There's no occurrences of the message "Account not found" in the git source, so I agree it's Springloops you want.

Answer (score 0):

When specifying a remote you would normally write:

```
user@host:repro
```

In your case your host uses a different port which you have to add by `:port` which forces you to use a more explicit way:

```
ssh://user@host:port/repro
```

See also:
[git remote add with other SSH port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596260/git-remote-add-with-other-ssh-port)

You can also have a look at `man git fetch`:

> GIT URLS
>          In general, URLs contain information about the transport protocol, the
>          address of the remote server, and the path to the repository. Depending
>          on the transport protocol, some of this information may be absent.
>
> ```
>    Git natively supports ssh, git, http, https, ftp, ftps, and rsync
>    protocols. The following syntaxes may be used with them:
>
>    ·   ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git/ [...]
>    An alternative scp-like syntax may also be used with the ssh protocol:
>
>    ·   [user@]host.xz:path/to/repo.git/
> ```