# Git - Use port 9418 for remote on github

Tags: git, bash, github

I am trying to connect to github at school but port 443 is blocked.

The admin told me to use port 9418 instead which I believe is the default port for the git protocol.

But in git bash (windows) if i try to do git remote set-url origin `git://github.com/me/myrepo.git` and do a push, it tells me I can't push to this URL, and to use `https://github...` instead.

How can I configure git to use port 9418 ?

Comment: For git protocol, the default port is 9418

Comment: tell your school IT to open port `443`. from a security perspective, your school should allow `https://` ("secure", that is "encrypted", http) rather than most other ports (including http)

Comment: Brief note, even if late: *"it tells me I can't push"* The `git://` protocol is anonymous and can only be used for fetching, cloning, etc., i.e. downloads. You cannot `git push` to any remote via the `git://` protocol because of this. I add this b/c the accepted answer does not explain *why* this works this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [github documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/pushing-to-a-remote#what-can-i-push-to):

> You can only push to one of two writeable protocol URL addresses. Those two include an SSH URL like git@github.com:user/repo.git or HTTPS URL like https://github.com/user/repo.git.

So you need open port 22 or 443 to work, git protocol is read only.

Comment: if port 22 it open - set origin to git@github.com:me/myrepo.git

Comment: connect to host github.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Comment: You probably configured something incorrectly or port 22 is closed

Answer (score 6):

check : [ReadyState4](http://readystate4.com/2011/03/30/working-with-git-repos-on-non-standard-ports/) or [git remote add with other ssh port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596260/git-remote-add-with-other-ssh-port)

One way : `git remote add origin ssh://git@domain.com:<port>/<project name>`

---

Second way :  change the `.git/config`

old:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = git@domain.com:<project name>
```

new:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    url = ssh://git@domain.com:<port>/<project name>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, it"ll ease your life

```
sed -i '/npm install/i \
RUN git config --global url."git@github.com:org".insteadOf 
"git://github.com/org" \
' Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

from this blog:https://github.blog/2021-09-01-improving-git-protocol-security-github/, github did not support git protocol anymore.

> On the Git protocol side, unencrypted git:// offers no integrity or
> authentication, making it subject to tampering. We expect very few
> people are still using this protocol, especially given that you can’t
> push (it’s read-only on GitHub). We’ll be disabling support for this
> protocol.

you should change the protocol with `ssh` or `https`.