# Clone SSH repository with non-standard port number to SourceTree

Tags: git, url, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

I spent about 20 minutes messing around with this problem.

I was emailed an SSH address for a repository. Crucially it had a non-standard (i.e. not 22) port number:
`git@domain.com:1234/opt/git/repository.git`

I assumed I could just copy-paste that into SourceTree, but kept getting `This is not a valid source path / URL` error messages.

When I took a closer look at the logs, the error was that it was looking for the path `1234/opt/git/repository.git` on the server - it was treating the *port number* as part of the path. And obviously not finding the repo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution was slightly weird:

1. Use a path like **`ssh://`**`git@domain.com:1234`**`:/`**`opt/git/repository.git`.
   Appending `ssh://`, and adding a `:` after the port number seemed to successfully act as a delimiter, and the path `/opt/git/repository.git` was found (as expected) on the server.
2. [Add the domain/port number to your config file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3596390/1053937) (e.g. `~/.ssh/config`) so that it looks like this:

`Host domain.com
    Port 1234`

Comment: I tried your answer on my Synology NAS running a Git Server. However, I had to delete the ':' after the port number in order to have a working URL. Therefore, with me it was (using your example): ssh://git@domain.com:1234/opt/git/repository.git

Comment: Same situation as reported by @Peter.